# How to check for text created by CSS?

Tags: html, css, behat

I have the following HTML:

```
<h4 id="myModalLabel"></h4>
```

I set the content in CSS:

```
#myModalLabel::after {
    content: "gebeurtenis";
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RobinvdA/7c3f1Lsk/)

This way, Behat can't seem to find the text when running this for example:

```
  Scenario: Viewing gebeurtenis
    Given I am on "hrm/calendar"
    Then I should see "gebeurtenis"
```

The result:

```
Then I should see "gebeurtenis"        # HRMContext::assertPageContainsText()
      The text "gebeurtenis" was not found anywhere in the text of the current page. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ResponseTextException)
```

How can I make it so this test will be successfull?

Comment: Pseudo elements are virtual/fake elements which are not part of the DOM. Are you trying to search for the text in DOM using behat?

Comment: I just started using Behat so i'm not sure, but i think that is how Behat works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I suggest a little trick, [css att()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr), to use a text in a pseudo and at the same time have it accessible in the DOM

```css
h4:after {
    content: attr(data-txt);
}
```

```html
<h4 id="myModalLabel"  data-txt="gebeurtenis">Here we go ... </h4>
```

If you still need to look for a text that might be (or you know) in a css rule, then you can do like this, though to scan all elements looking for "text hidden in pseudo css" might not be that speedy.

```js
var element = document.getElementById('div_1'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element,':after'),
    value = style.getPropertyValue('content').replace(/^\"|\"$/gm,''),
    result = document.getElementById('result');

if(value.length > 0) {
    result.innerHTML = 'Found in css: ' + value;
}
```

```css
#div_1 {
   color: red;
}
#div_1:after {
   content: 'world';
   color: blue;
}
#result {
   margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_1">hello </div>
<div id="result"></div>
```